# Using a 'date' data type in SQL Server Management Studio 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, datetime

I have a database with existing data that uses the datetime field which is a timestamp that uses date and time.

I want to just store the date, not the time, as the time is never used anyway but due to the way the app works it is causing inconsistencies when reporting on the data.

I believe there is a 'date' data type using the Design view on my table but when I tried to use that it said invalid data type. I also can't do this using the ALTER TABLE syntax in SQL.

Because it's live data, I don't want to make too many changes that might cause problems. We have a demo system that I can play around with though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL server 2008 has a `date` datatype, which only stores date

the easiest way to do is to alter the table like this:

```
alter table your_table alter column  <dt_col> date
```

Since you cannot alter the table , I think the only way left is convert while selecting

```
select convert(date,<dt_col>) from your_table
```

Or you can create a view with this select statement and use that view in all your queries

## [SQL fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f887b/1)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but I don't mind altering the table if needs be. The first one gives me the error "Column, parameter, or variable #24: Cannot find data type date." and the second gives me the error "Type date is not a defined system type.". It must be something to do with my SSMS version I think - it does say 2008 but maybe the server version is 2005. Thanks for the help

Comment: then it must be sql server 2005.. run this query to find the version  select @@VERSION

Comment: Yep - Microsoft SQL Server 2005. Thanks for the query.